# why "npm run dev" not woking while i sccessfully install npm?

Tags: laravel, npm

i installed the npm using command-line successfully but when i use to run `npm run dev` it shows me some errors!

i have tried to replace the code of `packages.json` provided on github and reinstall npm but still getting same error.

```
npm run dev

C:\wamp64\www\shopping>npm run dev
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe"
 "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is
  not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

@ dev C:\wamp64\www\shopping
npm run development

npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;

npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;

npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`

npm ERR! spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;

ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-28T19_22_32_311Z-debug.log
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17"
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please share your `package.json`?

Comment: Did you run "npm install"

Comment: Run `npm install npm -g`

Comment: @FerdieDeOliveira yes npm installed successfully

Comment: @RashedHasan npm install npm -g installed but while running dev still getting same error

Comment: make sure you havent installed npm locally without the `-g` flag. Cant really see an other issue. Also make sure you use the correct package.json from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json if you happen to come from an old laravel installation.

Comment: You may want to try `npm cache clean` and retry the install `npm install npm -g` to see that helps.